# Database Design: How to prevent referential integrity violation?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, relationship

Ok, maybe it's no the best title for the question, but this is the case.

I'm working on a project that already has an e-commerce. And part of the database looks like this. Everything works perfectly.

[image]

The problem comes with the references, if a user buys a product the shopping cart is closed, but if then the product is deleted or it's price changes the order becomes totally corrupted.

I've read this text -> [Database Design for Real-World E-Commerce Systems](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Il-Yeol_Song/publication/2359510_Database_Design_for_Real-World_E-Commerce_Systems/links/0912f514403695774c000000/Database-Design-for-Real-World-E-Commerce-Systems.pdf)
but I can't see the solution here.

What is the best way to do this. How big companies deal with this problem.
I mean what I need is to store all the details of an order with the data it had at the purchase moment.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to solve this. One approach is to have a price history table rather than a price column that changes periodically. When you create an order you create it for a given price and given product. When you need to change the price of the product, instead of changing the value of the price column, you enter a new record in your price history table so future orders can then take the new price. Another approach is to decouple the product price information from the order. Rather than take the price from the product table, you have a column for unit price in the order table and the current value for the price is saved there.

As far as deleting products, it depends again on your situation. Generally it's not a good idea to delete rows that are needed for historical information. So if you no longer want to sell a product, rather than delete the record, you could have a column that has the availability of the product set to false. So previous orders would still relate to that product but new orders wouldn't be able to add it.

Answer (score 0):

**Every instance of every field in a table should have a 1:1 relationship with that instance of the table.**
The problem is that the Price has a 1:1 relationship with the Product, which is good.  But it should also have a 1:1 relationship with the Cart.  And, since the price can change over time, it does not.
Two possible solutions: 1)Put a Timestamp on the Purchase, and keep all HistoricalPrices, then select the proper Price for the time of the purchase. This has the advantage of being able to tell exactly why the price changed, but can be extra work.  2)Add a PurchasePrice field to the Shopping_Cart_Products table.  Assign the PurchasePrice value for that instance of that table at the time the purchase is made.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices, if the products change while they're sitting in carts:

1. You update the cart and notify the user of the reason why.
2. You put all the information you need into the cart and work with that during checkout instead of the live product data.

Solution 1 requires you to do a sanity check *at least* once at the end of the checkout, to see if the cart is still valid. Solution 2 means that people may buy products that are somehow outdated.